# Combining spacyr and quanteda to produce a lemmatized corpus or dfm

Tags: r, quanteda

I understand how to build corpora and dfm with quanteda.
I also understand how to use spacy_parse to lemmatize a text or corpus object.

But I do not understand how to replace the original textual tokens with lemmas in my corpus.

I would expect something like:

```
corpus(my_txt) %>%
  dfm(lemmatize = spacy_parse)
```

To produce a matrix of lemmas, for example:

```
              be      have      go
first_text    2       6         6
second_text   4       4         2
third_text    6       4         3
```

Instead the only solution I found is to reassemble the lemmatized texts from the "lemma" column in the spacy_parse output dataframe, with some code like this one:

```
txt_parsed %>% 
select(doc_id, lemma) %>% 
group_by(doc_id) %>% 
summarise(new_txt = str_c(lemma, collapse = " "))
```

Any suggestions for a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quanteda::as.tokens()` to convert a spacy_parsed object to tokens.  Before this, you can swap the token column of the spacy_parsed object for the lemma column.

```r
txt <- c("I like having to be going.", "Then I will be gone.", "I had him going.")

library("spacyr")

sp <- spacy_parse(txt, lemma = TRUE, entity = FALSE, pos = FALSE)
## Found 'spacy_condaenv'. spacyr will use this environment
## successfully initialized (spaCy Version: 2.3.2, language model: en_core_web_sm)
## (python options: type = "condaenv", value = "spacy_condaenv")
sp$token <- sp$lemma

library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.0.0
## Unicode version: 10.0
## ICU version: 61.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
as.tokens(sp) %>%
  dfm()
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 9 features (37.04% sparse) and 0 docvars.
##        features
## docs    -pron- like have to be go . then will
##   text1      1    1    1  1  1  1 1    0    0
##   text2      1    0    0  0  1  1 1    1    1
##   text3      2    0    1  0  0  1 1    0    0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found an even easier solution, that is to use the use_lemma = T option in the as.tokens function.
Exemple:

```
library(spacyr)
spacy_initialize(model = "fr_core_news_sm")

sp1 <- spacy_parse(macron, lemma = TRUE, entity = FALSE, pos = FALSE)

dfm1 <- as.tokens(sp1, use_lemma = T) %>% dfm
```